# How to delete a file inside zip file in android

Tags: java, android, zip, truezip

I want to delete a file from a zip file without extracting it in android. I first did it with java using the following code

```
Path zipFilePath = Paths.get(filePaths); //gave the path of the zip with zip file name
try( FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zipFilePath, null) ){
    Path pathInZipfile = fs.getPath(reVsl3); //reVsl3 String which holds the name of the file to be deleted in  the zip file
  zipDelLoc=reVsl3; //just assigning it for future use
        System.out.println("About to delete an entry from ZIP File" + pathInZipfile.toUri() ); 
        // Execute Delete 
        Files.delete(pathInZipfile);
        System.out.println("File successfully deleted"); 
}
 catch (IOException e) {
     System.out.println(e+"Error here?");
}
```

This is working perfectly in netbeans, but its not working in ADT, the error occured in logcat

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.nio.file.Paths`

Isearched for a resolution in and got a hint that android does not have ' java.nio.file.Paths' this thing,
I am looking for an alternate solution can zip4j or TrueZip will do the trick here,

i tried with truezip, but with this code

```
TFile archive = new TFile("archive.zip");
for (String member : archive.list())
 System.out.println(member);
```

but archive.list() is returning null, but archive.length is returning its correct file size.

I dont know what i am doing wrong in here, i downloaded truezip 7.7 all in one jar. but i am getting an error when i give this `import de.schlichtherle.io.File`

please help

Comment: I guess you downloaded the wrong JAR file for TrueZIP. Please have a look at https://truezip.java.net/kick-start/no-maven.html . Also, please note that TrueZIP is in maintenance mode. For new projects, you should use TrueVFS. The respective page is https://truevfs.java.net/kick-start/no-maven.html .

Answer (score 0):

What version of Java are you using?

Double-check your import. It should be something something like `de.schlichtherle.truezip.nio.file.TPath;` When working with TrueZip, you need to import java.nio.paths even if you aren't using it and instead using truezip's flavor of paths.

Make sure you're including all the proper dependencies. I'm assuming you're using Gradle, so the dependency would look something like this:

```
'de.schlichtherle.truezip:truezip-file:7.7.9'
```

I handled a similar error with importing dependencies in a Java project using Maven. Try these things and provide your Java version.